# Why is my virtual machine's screen resolution so small?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I just started using Hyper-V, which comes with windows 8. I created a VM with windows 7. It works fine, even if a bit slow, but I can't get the screen resolution higher than 1152 by 768 even though the root windows goes up to 1680 by 1050.

I have installed the integration tools in the vm, do I need something else, display drivers maybe ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this answer via reddit, by user [6306](http://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/1csomg/why_is_my_virtual_machines_screen_resolution_so/c9jn84c) :

hyper-v has limited resolution when you access the console view, it's a professional virtualisation application and doesn't need fancy consumer features. The console view is effectively "sitting in front of the machine" view, most administration is done through remote desktop.

The best thing to do is download the excellent remote desktop metro app and rdp to your machine for full screen goodness. (enable remote access on the VM System Properties>Remote Tab)

Comment: Works beautifully when using Remote Desktop from the host.

Answer (score 0):

yes, try to update your display drivers to see whether it helps. From my past exp, it works. Not only to increase your resolution but also increased the picture quality.